# Is there some kind of way to import data that consists of multiple rows?

Tags: rapidminer

In RapidMiner the data table I usually see is like this:

```
Row    Age      Class
1      19       Adult
2      10       Minor
3      15       Teenager
```

In the data table above this sentence, one row refers to one complete information.

But how do I input a data table to RapidMiner where more than one row refers to one complete information?

For example:

```
Row      Word      Rho       Theta    Phi
1        Hello     0.9384    0.4943   1.2750
2        Hello     1.2819    0.8238   1.3465
3        Hello     1.3963    0.1758   1.4320
4        Eat       1.3918    0.3883   1.1756
5        Eat       1.4742    0.0526   1.2312
6        Eat       0.6698    0.2548   1.4769
7        Eat       0.3074    1.2214   0.2059
```

In the data table above this sentence, rows 1-3 refers to one complete information where the combinations of rho, theta, and phi from rows 1-3 means the word hello. Same goes for rows 4-7 which is one complete information also that means the word eat. For further explanation of the information I'm talking about, take a look at the table below this sentence.

```
Row     Rho       Theta      Phi      Word
        ----------------------------
1       |0.9384   0.4943     1.2750|
2       |1.2819   0.8238     1.3465|  HELLO
3       |1.3963   0.1758     1.4320|
        ----------------------------
4       |1.3918    0.3883    1.1756|
5       |1.4742    0.0526    1.2312|
6       |0.6698    0.2548    1.4769|  EAT
7       |0.3074    1.2214    0.2059|
        ----------------------------
```

Again my problem is, how do I insert this kind of data table to RapidMiner where it understands that multiple rows refer to one complete information? Is there some kind of table like what I displayed below this sentence?

```
Row      Word      Rho      Theta     Phi
1        Hello     0.9384    0.4943   1.2750
.        Hello     1.2819    0.8238   1.3465
1        Hello     1.3963    0.1758   1.4320
2        Eat       1.4742    0.0526   1.2312
.        Eat       0.6698    0.2548   1.4769
.        Eat       0.3074    1.2214   0.2059
2        Eat       0.3074    1.2214   0.2059
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the `Pivot` operator to group your result by word.

To do so, I would set the *group attribute* parameter to "Word" and the *index* parameter to "Row". It's not exactly the same representation, but close enough, depending on your use case, as multiple format tables are not part of RapidMiner's design.